# How to write multiple files using adobe flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flex4.5, mxml

I have a string array where each object has comma separated and new line delimiters. Now i want to write these string objects to multiple CSV files. But I am able to write only one CSV file as below:-

```
        /**
         * callback method for exportCollection, results are in format of Map<String, String>
         **/
        protected function exportListResultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void {
            if (event.result != null )
            {
                for (var key:* in event.result) {
                    var value:String=event.result[key];
                    var fileName:String=key;
                    exportStringToFile(value.toString(), fileName);
                }
            }
        }

        private function exportStringToFile(stringToExport:String, filename:String=null):void
        {               
            //file refernce for import/export functionality. 
            var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference(); 

            try{
                fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finishUpload);            
                fileRef.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleError);
                fileRef.save(stringToExport, filename);                
            }catch (error:Error){
                logger.error("Unable to save file. Error: ", error);  

        }
```

Mine existing codes do not allow me to use File class from flash.filesystem package. Even arrays of FileReference did not helped me. I want to save multiple file at one location.

I am new to Adobe flex and flash builder, Any help would be great. Thanks a a lot

Comment: Your code is looking good i guess - if you would have several keys in your result, it should save multiple files. So what is not working exactly ? Have you tried to debug and see if you have several different keys in your result?

Comment: Kishore, a browser app can't just save multiple files at once because of security reasons. The end-user must choose to click "save" on each file via a pop-up of dialogue box. That's your option or else, as suggested, make a zip file. Also why not `var value:String = String(event.result[key]);`? Try using `trace` in both functions to check that more than one entry gets through.

Answer (score 1):

If you're create AIR application? If yes why not using FileStream to save String to file?

```
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream;
stream.open (targetPath, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeUTFBytes (s);
stream.close();
```

Using FileReference to save file will open dialog box (security thing) and will annoying if you want to save multiple file

But if you working for non-AIR application / browser (web) based application other option is you can saved all files using server side code then download it on client. Of course this option will make your server do extra jobs especially for high traffics

Comment: I am using a browser based applications so i can't use FileStream. Can you please provide some option to download server side file.

Comment: what is your server side / backend programing language?
you need to process each file on backend than pack them all in zip file. before using FileReference to download the zip file

Comment: @Januartha, there is a ZIP file creator for using directly within AS3. It's called FZIP.

Comment: ah sure, using byteArray packed using any as3 Zip library
but you still need to create each your .csv files first

Comment: Thanks Januartha, I tried with servlet and i am able to work with that

Answer (score 1):

Flash player wont allow you to save multiple file in a loop. FP in browser have to open a file saving dialogue box to save the file. In the given scenario, simple and elegant way is to create a zip file on client side using nochump library and add each csv inside and then save that zip file on disk using browser flash player. A code example is following

```
var zipOut:ZipOutput=   new ZipOutput();
var ze1:ZipEntry    =   new ZipEntry("csv.csv");
zipOut.putNextEntry(ze1);
zipOut.write(byte_array_to_your_csv_string);
zipOut.closeEntry();
```

then ask the player to save this zip file.

You can download nochump AS3 from https://github.com/mazerte/openflow-as3/tree/master/src/nochump/util/zip